# PHPExcel: "Impossible to read file" error Converting Excel to PDF (.xlsx to .pdf)

Tags: php, pdf, phpexcel, xlsx

I have a xlsx with only one spreadsheet. I use PHPExcel to convert it to a pdf through the following code:

```
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
        require_once 'phpExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
        require_once 'phpExcel/PHPExcel.php';

        $inputFileName = 'doc/ModUnico';
        $excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $excel2 = $excel2->load($inputFileName.'.xlsx');
        $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H5', '4');
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save($inputFileName.'_.xlsx');


        $objPHPexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName.'_.xlsx');
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.pdf"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel, 'PDF');
        $objWriter->writeAllSheets();
        $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

The problem is that when i try to open the returned file i get the error message "Impossible to read file".

EIDT: Renderer added

```
        $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;
        $rendererLibrary = 'mpdf.php';
        $rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/MPDF57/' . $rendererLibrary;


        if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
            $rendererName,
            $rendererLibraryPath
            )) {
                die(
                    'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
                    '<br />' .
                    'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
                );
        }
```

Comment: did you save the file to disc and open it in a text/hex editor to see what was REALLY downloaded?

Comment: Do you actually need to create the intermediate `$inputFileName.'_.xlsx'` file? I don't see the point in that

Comment: But where are you identifying the PDF Rendering engine to use when writing the PDF file? Are you using tcPDF, mPDF, DomPDF?

Comment: Have you tried opening the downloaded file in a text editor, to see if it contains any obvious leading/trailing whitespace characters, BOM headers, PHP error messages, etc?

Comment: @Marc-b Yes and the downloaded file is corrupted, it's not valid, gives me an error by opening.

Comment: @Mark-Baker The intermediate file is only a test, to check if the setCellValue('H5', '4'); works fine. What do you mean with  identifying the PDF Rendering engine?

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't include an actual PDF Rendering engine library, juts wrappers to three of the more popular libraries, but you need to install either tcPDF, mPDF or DomPDF separately, and point PHPExcel to which one you have installed - See section `6.9.1` ("PHPExcel_Writer_PDF") of the developer documentation, and example `01simple-download-pdf.php` in the `/Examples` folder

Comment: ok, rendere added...but the result is the same.

Comment: Then open the file in a text editor and look for the aforementioned leading/trailing whitespace characters, any visible error messages, etc

Comment: OK, when i comment the headers, i got the html error page:
( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files (x86)\Wamp\www\Terzer\MPDF57\mpdf.php on line 30620 
Call Stack

Comment: Well you are still saving as Excel2007 and then reloading again, all of which takes time; remove those spurious overheads and see if that reduces the execution time enough for the pdf writer to finish its work; and/or increase execution time

Comment: I removed parts of code, got same result/error. Are you sure that ALL xlsx are supported?

Comment: I've just tried a simple xlsx...and it works. not good.

Comment: Then increase your PHP execution time

Comment: If you are only interested in the data and don't care about formatting, then you might gain a lot of speed by telling PHPExcel you only want the data: `$excel2->setReadDataOnly(true);` Do this before the call to `load()`. It will still process stuff like formulas. Also you might want to use the identify function to create the correct reader: `$fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename); $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($filetype);` The filetype is a string, so you can echo it for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I think Mark is on to something.  When I run into errors like this, I start at the top and work down.  i.e.  Is the intermediate xlsx file correct?

I would probably also write some test code with REALLY simple xls files, or csv files that uses the PHPExcel library, and you should figure out what's wrong while you try to get those to work.  Same with the pdf renderer, I would try a different one (if one is available).

Joey

Comment: Hi, Xlsx file is correct, it is valid and openable once modified. I did some tests and i noticed that if i reduce the xlsx it works, so i fear the problem is that the complex xlsx to manage.