# How to convert a xlsx file into pdf using php

Tags: php, pdf, phpexcel

I am in searching to find a solution to convert the .xlsx(Excel) file into pdf files.

```
require_once('phpExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
require_once('phpexcel/PHPExcel.php');

$fileType = 'Excel5';
$fileName = 'testing.xlsx';
$outputFileType = 'PDF';
$outputFileName = 'test.pdf';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $outputFileType);
$objWriter->writeAllSheets();
$objWriter->save($outputFileName);
```

I used this above code,but is not working. If any can an Idea, please help me

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797737/converting-excel-to-pdf-xlsx-to-pdf-using-phpexcel  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: So which rendering engine are you using for PDF? It's not visible in your code at all. See section `6.9` of the developer documentation for details on writing to PDF